# how to get jpg files from psd files in adobe photoshop

Tags: image, adobe

I need to get the image files for circle player in 40 *40 pixels from the psd files given here https://github.com/maboa/circleplayer.How to get those in adobe photoshop?

The psd file given is of 800 *800 pixel .When I try to reduce the image size to 100 *100 pixels ,the canvas size seems too large and the image seems too small.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about cropping I believe. You have to figure out what you do and do not want.
Select what area you want, crop, then resize the canvas, finally the image.

Step by Step Process of Resizing:
http://www.photoshopessentials.com/essentials/image-resizing/

Now to get as a JPG, PNG, etc: File > Save for Web > Find the file type you wish.